# How to interrupt getchar in second thread with SIGINT

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, console, stdin

I need to handle SIGINT in my console application, I found many examples about sa_flags = 0; of sigaction structure - and it's mean getchar will be aborted and return -1. But this is not working with multithreading

Look at my code

```
int p[2];
FILE *stdin_writer = nullptr;

void int_handler(int signum)
{
    //////do nothing

    //////or write something into stdin..... also no help

    //write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1);

    //////using pipes deadlocks application

    //stdin_writer = fdopen(p[1], "w");
    //fputc('g', stdin_writer);
}

void run()
{

    //pipe(p);
    //dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);

    printf("before getchar\n");
    auto c = getchar();
    printf("after getchar\n");
}

int main()
{
    //////Setup SIGINT handler

    struct sigaction sh;

    sh.sa_handler = int_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sh.sa_mask);
    sh.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sh, NULL);
    return 0;

    //////Setup console

    termios _prev{ 0 };
    // grab old terminal i/o settings
    tcgetattr(0, &_prev);
    // make new settings same as old settings 
    auto current = _prev;
    // disable buffered i/o
    current.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    // set no echo mode
    current.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;

    // use these new terminal i/o settings now
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &current);

    std::thread trd(&run);

    trd.join();
}
```

I want to interrupt getchar on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - similar code works just fine in single thread version (without std::thread stuff), but not in multithread. Please help me anyone - I am already stuck in this problem on whole day

Comment: When a process receives a signal, it can be directed to any thread that does not have it blocked.  Thus, if you want to be sure that the `getchar()` is interrupted by the signal then you must make sure that the signal is delivered to its thread by blocking it in all other threads.

Comment: My application is very big(its just test code), so i don't know all threads of my app, threads could be created by plugins, or in other user code or in 3rd libs. So i can't use this solution...

Comment: There is no other solution, @fsmoke.  If you want to rely on using a signal to interrupt a system call, then you *must* take appropriate measures to ensure that the signal is delivered to the thread in which that syscall is running.  If you cannot ensure that, then you need an altogether different approach.

Comment: " If you want to rely on using a signal to interrupt a system call", sorry but i don't know other way to interrupt getchar.. may be there is another way..without signals??

Comment: @JohnBollinger you little bit wrong about "There is no other solution"...cos finally I found the right solution. See below.

Comment: Nothing in your answer contradicts anything I said, @fsmoke.  You have given up on the SIGINT generated by the keystroke necessarily being delivered to any specific thread, so your approach does not satisfy the conditions expressed in my previous comments, and `pthread_kill` directs a signal to a specific thread, not to a whole process.  You're welcome for being nudged in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the right solution. SIGINT signal interrupts getchar operation only if this signal sent to the same thread with getchar. So if your application have tons of threads - we have situation in which probability of catching SIGINT in right thread is very small. So you will be pending getchar infinitely....

But! if we will carafully read pthread documentation about pthread_kill function we can see this line

> pthread_kill - send a signal to a thread

pthread_kill - not killing thread in fact it's send signal. Eureka! We can resend signal SIGINT into the right thread. See code below

```
std::optional<std::thread> trd;
std::mutex mtx;

void int_handler(int signum)
{
    std::lock_guard lk(mtx);
    if (trd && std::this_thread::get_id() != trd->get_id())
        pthread_kill(trd->native_handle(), signum);
}

void run()
{
    printf("before getchar\n");
    auto c = getchar();
    printf("after getchar\n");
}

int main()
{
    //////Setup SIGINT handler

    struct sigaction sh;

    sh.sa_handler = int_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sh.sa_mask);
    sh.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sh, NULL);
    return 0;

    //////Setup console

    termios _prev{ 0 };
    // grab old terminal i/o settings
    tcgetattr(0, &_prev);
    // make new settings same as old settings 
    auto current = _prev;
    // disable buffered i/o
    current.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    // set no echo mode
    current.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;

    // use these new terminal i/o settings now
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &current);

    {
        std::lock_guard lk(mtx);
        trd.emplace(&run);
    }

    trd->join();
}
```